# mysqli_query in PHP with SET

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, set

I have a little problem with a sql query in PHP. I have search on internet, but I don't have find my answer.

```
$row = "(null, @last_id, '000000', 'NAME', 100.00);";

mysqli_query($con,"
    INSERT INTO receipt
    VALUES (null, '$datetimeSQL', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
    SET @last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    INSERT INTO receipt_product
    VALUES $row
");
```

INSERT INTO and VALUES work but it's dossen't work when I add the other part. I think the problem is the SET, but i'm not sure. My code work fine with SQL in phpMyAdmin.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I don't think the semicolon at the end of the VALUES line can be there. It should be a comma, no?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to execute these as separate queries, and call `mysqli_insert_id()` to get the last insert id instead of trying to do it all in one query call. The MySQL libraries often won't execute multiple statements in a single call for security reasons.

The `SET` line you have in your original query needs to be replaced with this code call between the statements.

```
$id = (int)mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

[`mysqli_insert_id()`](http://php.net/mysqli_insert_id) will return the last value generated by `AUTO_INCREMENT` for a primary key, so in this case it will return the receipt id generated by inserting `NULL` into the column.

So, with proper error checking and separate statements, your code should looks something like this:

```
// If you aren't already escaping the datetime with mysqli_real_escape_string, you need to do this:
$datetimeSQL = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $datetimeSQL);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `receipt`
        VALUES (null, '{$datetimeSQL}', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if ($result) {
    $id = (int)mysqli_insert_id($con);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `receipt_product`
            VALUES (null, {$id}, '000000', 'NAME', 100.00);"
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if (!$result) {
        print('MySQL error: [' . mysqli_errno($con) . '] ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
} else {
    print('MySQL error: [' . mysqli_errno($con) . '] ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

You can also call the `mysqli_*()` functions as methods of the [`mysqli`](http://php.net) class by dropping the `mysqli_` prefix and calling them as methods on the `$con` object, so `mysqli_query($con, $sql)` becomes `$con->query($sql)`, `mysqli_errno($con)` becomes `$con->errno()`, and so on and so forth.

As an additional note, it's good practice to always define the column names you are providing when executing `INSERT` statements as this allows your queries to continue to function correctly if you add additional columns to the table later on. For example, if the `receipt` table contains columns named `id`, `created_at`, and `modified_at`, and `id` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` primary key, and `modified_at` has `DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00` in its definition, then your first query simply becomes this:

```
INSERT INTO `receipt` (
    `created_at`
) VALUES (
    '{$datetimeSQL}'
);
```